# How do I show a semidirect product of relatively-prime ordered groups is isomorphic to the direct product of those groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semidirect-product, direct-product

Here is my question:

Given that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime positive integers, and $\alpha$ is some group homomorphism $\alpha: \Bbb{Z}_{b} \rightarrow \text{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_{a})$, where $\text{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_{a})$ is the automorphism group of $\Bbb{Z}_{a}$, how do I show that $\Bbb{Z}_{a} \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{b} \cong \Bbb{Z}_{a} \times \Bbb{Z}_{b}$ as groups?

Here is my thought process so far: It follows easily that $\Bbb{Z}_{a}$ (or an isomorphic copy thereof) is a normal subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}_{a} \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{b}$, basically by construction of a semidirect product. Similarly, $\Bbb{Z}_{a} \cap \Bbb{Z}_{b} = \{0\}$ as subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}_{a} \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{b}$.

If I can show that $\Bbb{Z}_{b}$ is also a normal subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}_{a} \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{b}$, then the desired isomorphism follows. One way to show this is to show that $\Bbb{Z}_{a} \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{b} \cong \Bbb{Z}_{b} \rtimes_{\beta} \Bbb{Z}_{a}$ for some group homomorphism $\beta: \Bbb{Z}_{a} \rightarrow \text{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_{b})$, because then $\Bbb{Z}_{b}$ is normal in both of those semidirect products. But this has been very difficult, since we don't know *what* $\alpha$ is.

I have also tried brute-forcing this by trying to construct an isomorphism between the two groups, but that hasn't gotten me anywhere.

Comment: $S_3$ is the semi direct product of two cyclic groups of relatively prime orders.

Comment: @lulu I've never heard this before, and I'm not finding anything online about it either. Is there some obvious intuition as to why that's true?

Comment: $S_3$ is the most basic example of a semi-direct product.  See any reference at all.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20there%20is%20a,(D6%20%E2%8B%89%20V).) for example.

Comment: @lulu Oh, I see what you were saying. I thought you meant that EVERY semidirect product of relatively-prime-ordered groups was isomorphic to $S_{3}$, which is why I was initially confused. That being said, I don't see any reference to $S_{3}$ on that Wikipedia article, but I see what you're getting at.

Comment: If you want more counterexamples to the claim you are trying to prove, just use the dihedral groups $D_n$ for odd $n$.  Of course, $D_3\simeq S_3$ so this just generalizes the $S_3$ example.  (It's probably as $D_3$ that $S_3$ appears in that article).

Comment: OP, you've been given a good class of counterexamples, but there is a similar condition where this holds. If $\phi(a)$ and $b$ are relatively prime then the only semidirect product $\mathbb Z/a \rtimes \mathbb Z/b$ is the direct product. Here, $\phi$ denotes the totient function.