# Proving a semidirect product of two groups is isomorphic to the direct product of the same groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am wondering if there is a relation between semidirect product of two groups and the direct product using the same groups?

For example, if a group $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_{26} \rtimes \mathbf{Z}_{5}$ for some homomorphism from $\mathbf{Z}_{5}$ to Aut$(\mathbf{Z}_{26})$. How can I prove that $H$ is also isomorphic to the direct product $\mathbf{Z}_{26} \times \mathbf{Z}_{5}$?

I have no clue where to start. Can someone please enlighten me how to approach this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A pointer: "no clue" questions [are heavily discouraged](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions) here. Please improve your question with an [edit], otherwise it is likely to be closed.

Comment: If $H$ is normal in $N \rtimes H$, then $N \rtimes H \cong N \times H$. It's also helpful to know in this case that for a non-trivial homormorphism $\phi \colon H \to \operatorname{Aut}(N)$, $N \rtimes H$ is never abelian.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\Bbb{Z}_{26} \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{5} \cong \Bbb{Z}_{26} \times \Bbb{Z}_{5}$ as groups.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4138394/bbbz-26-rtimes-alpha-bbbz-5-cong-bbbz-26-times-bbbz-5)

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4137695/how-do-i-show-a-semidirect-product-of-relatively-prime-ordered-groups-is-isomorp).